# OpenCV: Drawing boundary over detected motion

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, contour

I am a newbie to OpenCV and decided to learn it but writing a small program that detects motion and draws a bounding box on the object.

I started with a rather simple method that simply calculated the difference between two frames, finds contours and drew a simple rectangle around the object. This served its purpose for a while but it was incapable of autonomously tracking multiple objects as they popped up. I had to manually change my parameters for it to track ***n*** number of objects.

So I decided to change my method and instead use `BackgroundSubtractorMOG`. This method is more favorable for what I am trying to accomplish but the only issue that I am currently having is how to draw an outline of the detected object(s) after applying `BackgroundSubtractorMOG`. I don't want rectangles anymore instead I want it to draw around the object's border.

```
import sys
import cv2

def getImageDifference(first, second):
    return cv2.absdiff(first, second)

def drawRectangle(contour, frame):
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

previousFrame = None
backgroundSubtractor = None
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
backgroundSubtractor = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()

while True:
    grabbed, frame = camera.read()

    if not grabbed:
        break

    fgMask = backgroundSubtractor.apply(frame, learningRate = 1.0/10)
    output = cv2.GaussianBlur(fgMask, (21, 21), 0)

    if previousFrame is None:
        previousFrame = fgMask
        continue

    frameDelta = getImageDifference(previousFrame, output)
    maskRGB = cv2.cvtColor(fgMask,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    frameDela = maskRGB
#    frameDelta = cv2.cvtColor(fgMask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    threshold = cv2.threshold(fgMask, 21, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    threshold = cv2.dilate(threshold, None, iterations = 2)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    sortedContours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:2] #this will track two objects simultaneously. If I want more, I'd have to come and change this value to whatever I want

    for contour in sortedContours:

        drawRectangle(contour, frame)
        previousFrame = output

    draw = frame & maskRGB

    cv2.imshow('Main',frame)
    cv2.imshow('Background Subtraction', fgMask)
    cv2.imshow('Background Subtraction with color', draw)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: So what is your question, exactly? How do you draw a bounding box around the detected contours? Have a look at the `highgui` module. There's loads of examples on doing exactly this in the docs.

Comment: @gavinb What i want is being able to draw a border around the actual object as show [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WhqYV9DCJ0). With my current method, I am simply drawing rectangles around the contours rather than drawing borders along the object